# Trying to plot a column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot a column I created from the original data set called "Daily Changes" but this is not working and I do not know why. I created "Daily Changes" using a loop in #2. #3 is how I am trying to plot this.

```
#libraries 
pacman::p_load(dplyr, fpp3, GGally, tsibbledata)
theme_set(theme_classic())
#1
AMZN_2018 <- gafa_stock %>%
  filter(Date >= "2018-01-01" & Date <= "2018-12-31" & Symbol == "AMZN")
print(AMZN_2018)
#2
AMZN_2018 %>%
  group_by(Symbol) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate("Daily Changes" = Close - lag(Close, default = first(Close)))
#3
AMZN_Plot <- autoplot("Daily Changes") + ylab("Daily Change") + xlab("Date") +
  ggtitle("Daily AMZN Stock Change 2018")
AMZN_Plot
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome. Thank you for providing code, but it is not very useful since we dont have your data. Adding data will greatly help in the quality and speed of responses. You can add data several ways, for instance by creating dummy data, or copying and pasting the output of `dput(your_data)`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your step 2 is just outputting, not assigning the output back to anything. Try using the assignment pipe operator, `%<>%` instead of `%>%` in the first part of the pipe. As @zephryl notes, you'll also need the `{magrittr}` package:

```
library(magrittr) 
 
AMZN_2018 %<>%
  group_by(Symbol) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate("Daily Changes" = Close - lag(Close, default = first(Close)))
```

Comment: NB, `%<>%` isn't re-exported by `dplyr`, so you'd also need to load `library(magrittr)`.

Comment: Oh, this is true - thanks very much, @zephryl, for the reminder. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you all, this was helpful and I figured out what I needed to do.